# T4MVC ModelBinding

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I had the following Action:

```
public ActionResult GetCityObjects(string cityAlias)
```

By some reasons I added a custom ModelBinder:

```
public ActionResult GetCityObjects(City city)
```

Now I want to make T4MVC add "cityAlias" parameter with value city.Alias when I pass city parameter to appropriate T4MVC method. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now possible with T4MVC Model Unbinder feature (http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation 3.1), you could implement custom unbinder for `City` type like that:

```
public class CityUnbinder : IModelUnbinder<City>
{
    public void UnbindModel(RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary, string routeName, City city)
    {
        if (user != null)
            routeValueDictionary.Add("cityAlias", city.Alias);
    }
}
```

and then register it in T4MVC (from Application_Start):

```
ModelUnbinderHelpers.ModelUnbinders.Add(new CityUnbinder());
```

After that you can normally use MVC.Home.GetCityObjects(city) for generating urls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

You need to use the parameterless version and add route values manually:

```
GetCityObjects().AddRouteValue("cityAlias", city.cityAlias)
```

If you look at the source code you will see that the generated method just adds `city` instance using parameter name 'city'.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. I have hardcoded the following to T4MVC:

```
<#foreach (var method in controller.ActionMethods) { #>
        public override <#=method.ReturnTypeFullName #> <#=method.Name #>(<#method.WriteFormalParameters(true); #>) {
            var callInfo = new T4MVC_<#=method.ReturnType #>(Area, Name, ActionNames.<#=method.ActionName #>);
<#if (method.Parameters.Count > 0) { #>
<#foreach (var p in method.Parameters) { #>
<#  if (p.Name != "city") { #>
        callInfo.RouteValueDictionary.Add(<#=p.RouteNameExpression #>, <#=p.Name #>);
<# } #>
<# else #>
<# { #>
       callInfo.RouteValueDictionary.Add("cityAlias", city.Alias);
<# } #>
<#} #>
<#}#>
            return callInfo;
        }
```

I can't say I like it, but at least it works in my case.

David, what do you think about introducing a more general implementation of this into T4MVC?

Comment: That sounds good in principle! Just need to find contributors who have time to work on this, as unfortunately I only have limited resources to work on T4MVC. Though I try to fix bugs with obvious fixes quickly.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, I hope I can find some time to implement it, but first I would like to discuss what to implement. It would be great to generalize similar cases and find out a best way to cover them